# How to get rid of Websphere traditional error for Windows local development - Java8

Tags: java, websphere

We have a pretty standard Java J2EE Web and Ear application, where we have an ear with web applications (no ejbs or web services) but we do have security involved and a database jndi configuration.  But for some reason, we keep getting these SSL errors.

It could be related that we use the CAR import restore/backup with RAD IDE and Websphere traditional.  Don't know.

We get this ssl message and seems to stop the server from starting.  The ssl settings which we aren't using go out for 1 year into 2025 so no not expired.  What is admin-authz?

```
[2/21/24 17:58:20:930 EST] 00000057 SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection.  Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired.  Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at com.ibm.jsse2.c.a(c.java:12)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:257)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.unwrap(as.java:528)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:5)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:586)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:346)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

.
[2/21/24 17:58:20:934 EST] 00000057 RoleBasedAuth A   SECJ0305I: The role-based authorization check failed for admin-authz operation Server:getState.  The user UNAUTHENTICATED (unique ID: unauthenticated) was not granted any of the following required roles: configurator, administrator, auditor, monitor, deployer, adminsecuritymanager, operator.

Here is the startup message with settings:

```
WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.15 [BASE 8.5.5.15 cf151904.01] running with process name user-10Node03Cell\user-10Node03\server1 and process id 3616
```

Host Operating System is Windows 10, version 10.0
Java version = 1.8.0_191, Java Runtime Version = 8.0.5.27 - pwa6480sr5fp27-20190104_01(SR5 FP27), Java Compiler = j9jit29, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85
user.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv01
Java Home = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/java/lib;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/classes;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/installedChannels;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/ext;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/web/help;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/properties;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/startup.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/java/lib/tools.jar
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb80-20181016.00